# Calculation within html table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a project where I need to calculate some numbers in html table. they'll need to see the end sum.
Is there any other way that can calculate the value without using `<input>` tag. If I use , the display will become like box within box, like the picture below: 
[image]

My code is below:

```
<tr oninput="Total-dep.value=parseInt(Dep-main.value)+parseInt(Dep-joint1.value)">
   <td>No. of Dependant(s)</td>
   <td contenteditable="true" id="Dep-main" value="0"></td>
   <td contenteditable="true" id="Dep-joint1" value="0"></td>
   <td contenteditable="true" name="Total-dep" for="Dep-main Dep-joint1" value=""></td>
</tr>
```

The current display result is below: 
[image]

I want to use the first two column to add up together and then sum up in the last column.

Comment: Can you share your try!

Comment: the event should be `onblur`

Comment: You could use CSS to modify the appearance of each input box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `input` element and just style it to not have any borders.

Also, the `name` and `value` attributes are only valid on form elements and the `for` attribute is not valid on `td` elements either.

Lastly, a `tr` element doesn't have an `input` event, only form elements do.

```js
// Do all your JavaScript in a separate JavaScript section
var main = document.getElementById("Dep-main");
var joint1 = document.getElementById("Dep-joint1");
var total = document.getElementById("Total-dep");

var inputs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("td > input"));

inputs.forEach(function(input){

  input.addEventListener("blur", function(){
    // Always supply the second argument to parseInt() (the radix) so you
    // dont' get non-base 10 answers.
    total.value = parseInt(main.value, 10) + parseInt(joint1.value, 10);
  });

});
```

```css
td { border:1px solid black; }
td > input { border:none; } /* Remove normal border */
td > input:active, td > input:focus { outline:none; } /* Remove outline when active or focused */
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Other</td>
  <td>Some</td>
  <td>Other</td>
  <td>Row</td>
</tr>
<tr id="row">
   <td>No. of Dependant(s)</td>
   <td><input type="text" id="Dep-main" value="0"></td>
   <td><input type="text" id="Dep-joint1" value="0"></td>
   <td><input type="text" id="Total-dep" readonly></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can hide the border of the input text field using css.

```
{
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```